# How to fetch data from multiple table using core data in Swift.?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new to core data. How to create a Fetch Request that can fetch data from two tables ?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set the entity inheritance for your two entities and use the concept of abstract entity. You can refer the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096250/core-data-any-way-to-fetch-multiple-entities)