# How to sort the same attribute from different entities in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have three entities: `Entity1`, `Entity2` and `Entity3`, they all have an attribute `date`. I want to get the latest date, not care about which entity it belongs to.

My solution is to fetch these three entities separately and get **date1**, **date2** and **date3** as the latest dates for them, then compare the three dates to get the real latest date.

This is not elegant, how to accomplish the task efficiently?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a Main Entities, from which Entity1, Entity2 and Entity3 would inherits from. That way, you should be able to perform only on fetch See there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096250/core-data-any-way-to-fetch-multiple-entities Or you could create a new entity that would handle the date, and is linked to the other one and fetch on this entity.

Comment: @Larme The link is very helpful